# How do I get the angle in radians (0 to 2pi) from a quaternion?

Tags: navigation, simulation, odometry, stage, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the angle of a position model in Stage in radians from the Odometry message published to the "odom" topic.

This is how I've done it:

```
theta = 2 * asin(msg.pose.pose.orientation.z);
```

This sort of works in getting the angle in radians, but whenever the angle is below the x axis it gives me a negative angle.

Is there anyway of getting the angle in radians going from 0 to 2pi, starting from the positive x axis going anti-clockwise?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41392/how-do-i-get-the-angle-in-radians-(0-to-2pi)-from-a-quaternion?/) by [Clefairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3004/clefairy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look in the angles package. There is a header with functions that normalize the radian. I think there is also one for [0, 2 Pi).

For getting yaw of a quaternion, there should be a function in tf that does this for you.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-14**:
You are looking for the tf::getYaw function: http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b